# Metropolis-Hastings algorithm case when both transition probabilities are 0

Tags: probability, markov-chains, monte-carlo

[image]

What happens in the case where $q(y|x)$ and $q(x|y)$ are both 0? I'm not sure whether we would just return 1 from the min operation since the quotient is indeterminate, or if we would return something else.

Comment: Since you are generating from $q(y|x)$ you (almost surely) won't be sampling a point $Y$ such that $q(y|x) = 0$

Comment: I'm considering a process where you have four states, 00, 01, 10, 11, and the probability of going from one state to another is 0.5 if they differ in exactly one bit, 0 otherwise. There are 8 zeros in the 4x4 transition probability matrix.

Comment: The proposal, $q$ is free for you to choose - it may be that you are generating values which have zero probability under the distribution you are trying to sample from, i.e. $f(y)=0$, but you won't sample a value of $Y$ from the proposal for which $q(Y|x) = 0$.

Comment: After thinking about it some more it seems like we'd want to return 1, since we want $\rho(x, y)$ to represent a valid probability. We can't choose the indeterminate form 0/0, so we must choose 1.

Comment: Again I think something is already going very wrong if you are in a position that you need to evaluate the proposal at a point $y$ for which you have $q(y|x) = 0$ - and that is more important than what even convention you want want to adopt, after all $0/0 = 1$ is fine but what about $q(x|y)/0$ with $q(x|y) > 0$ and so on.